# Sqlite WHERE Clause using Parameters

Tags: c#, sqlite

Trying to run a specific query using a where clause, here is what I have.

```
//ID is user input could be anything
SqliteParameter Identifier = new SqliteParameter ("@ID", ID);
string SQLText = "SELECT Email FROM Client WHERE Email=@ID;"
SqliteCommand Command = new SqliteCommand (SQLText, Database);
Command.Parameters.Add (Identifier);
string Result = Command.ExecuteScalar ().ToString ();
return Result;
```

The Error I get is:

> SqliteSyntaxException: near "="; syntax error

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `SELECT Value FROM Table WHERE **ID**=@ID`??? If you know the value already, why try to select it?

Comment: @Ron: I am comparing the value to user input.

Comment: Maybe `Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;`

Comment: Table is a reserved keyword, put it between square brackets [Table] and then, the field named Value is a text field?

Comment: @Kryptos: If I run just the select without the where it works fine. So probably don't need to specify command type. I assume anyhow.

Comment: @Steve: Table isn't really the name of the table (Client is the real name), all Value is a "STRING" field, I thought STRING == TEXT in sqlite. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Usually a Syntax Error with no obvious syntax error is caused by a reserved keyword, What is the real name of the column named `Value`?

Comment: Nope, you could [check this list](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) but lacking more info I can only suggest to enclose every object name in square brackets

Comment: I just created a sample fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/21c35/1/0 No problems with that, so I am voting to close.

Comment: @ Steve & Andreas: It seems that putting my variables in brackets ( [Email]) seems to have done the trick. I appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue the other day. The issue that I was using keywords as objects.
To avoid syntax errors you might want to escape your objects, like:

```
SELECT [Email] FROM [Client] WHERE [Email] = @ID;
```